# Entity Framework Core : performance slow when loading entities with deep includes

Tags: c#, ef-core-3.1

I am facing query performance issue when loading entities with a lot of `Include`s and `ThenInclude`s.

Each entity has around 2 to 3 levels of `ThenInclude`s.

The following is a sample of my entity class:

```cs
public class EntityA {
    public EntityB ItemOne { get; set; }
    public EntityC ItemTwo { get; set; }
    public EntityD ItemThree { get; set; }
    public EntityE ItemFour { get; set; }
    public EntityF ItemFive { get; set; }
    public EntityG ItemSix { get; set; }
    public List<EntityI> ItemSeven { get; set; }
    public List<EntityI> ItemEight { get; set; }
}

public class EntityB {
    public EntityJ AnotherProperty { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class EntityJ {
    public EntityK SomeProperty { get; set; }
}
... // Remaining entity classes
```

My current query:

```cs
protected virtual IQueryable<RecommendedBuild> QueryWithDetails => _queryWithDetails ??= _db.RecommendedBuilds
            .Include(u => u.BuildDetail)
                .ThenInclude(u => u.Casing)
                    .ThenInclude(c => c.HardwareImage)
            .Include(u => u.BuildDetail)
                .ThenInclude(u => u.Casing)
                    .ThenInclude(c => c.CasingType)
            .Include(u => u.BuildDetail)
                .ThenInclude(u => u.Casing)
                    .ThenInclude(c => c.Color)
            .Include(u => u.BuildDetail)
                .ThenInclude(u => u.Casing)
                    .ThenInclude(c => c.SidePanelWindow)
            .Include(u => u.BuildDetail)
                .ThenInclude(u => u.Casing)
                    .ThenInclude(c => c.Manufacturer)
            .Include(u => u.BuildDetail)
                .ThenInclude(u => u.Casing)
                    .ThenInclude(c => c.FrontPanelUsbs)
                        .ThenInclude(c => c.LookValue)
            .Include(u => u.BuildDetail)
                .ThenInclude(u => u.Casing)
                    .ThenInclude(c => c.MotherboardFormFactors)
                        .ThenInclude(c => c.LookValue)

            .Include(u => u.BuildDetail)
                .ThenInclude(u => u.CpuCooler)
                    .ThenInclude(c => c.Manufacturer)
            .Include(u => u.BuildDetail)
                .ThenInclude(u => u.CpuCooler)
                    .ThenInclude(c => c.Bearing)
            .Include(u => u.BuildDetail)
                .ThenInclude(u => u.CpuCooler)
                    .ThenInclude(c => c.HardwareImage)
            .Include(u => u.BuildDetail)
                .ThenInclude(u => u.CpuCooler)
                    .ThenInclude(c => c.Sockets)
                        .ThenInclude(c => c.LookValue)

            .Include(u => u.BuildDetail)
                .ThenInclude(u => u.Cpu)
                    .ThenInclude(c => c.Manufacturer)
            .Include(u => u.BuildDetail)
                .ThenInclude(u => u.Cpu)
                    .ThenInclude(c => c.Series)
            .Include(u => u.BuildDetail)
                .ThenInclude(u => u.Cpu)
                    .ThenInclude(c => c.Family)
            .Include(u => u.BuildDetail)
                .ThenInclude(u => u.Cpu)
                    .ThenInclude(c => c.Socket)
            .Include(u => u.BuildDetail)
                .ThenInclude(u => u.Cpu)
                    .ThenInclude(c => c.IntegratedGraphic)
            .Include(u => u.BuildDetail)
                .ThenInclude(u => u.Cpu)
                    .ThenInclude(c => c.Lithography)
            .Include(u => u.BuildDetail)
                .ThenInclude(u => u.Cpu)
                    .ThenInclude(c => c.HardwareImage)

            .Include(u => u.BuildDetail)
                .ThenInclude(u => u.GraphicCard)
                    .ThenInclude(c => c.Manufacturer)
            .Include(u => u.BuildDetail)
                .ThenInclude(u => u.GraphicCard)
                    .ThenInclude(c => c.ChipSet)
            .Include(u => u.BuildDetail)
                .ThenInclude(u => u.GraphicCard)
                    .ThenInclude(c => c.MemoryType)
            .Include(u => u.BuildDetail)
                .ThenInclude(u => u.GraphicCard)
                    .ThenInclude(c => c.Interface)
            .Include(u => u.BuildDetail)
                .ThenInclude(u => u.GraphicCard)
                    .ThenInclude(c => c.Color)
            .Include(u => u.BuildDetail)
                .ThenInclude(u => u.GraphicCard)
                    .ThenInclude(c => c.SliCrossFireType)
            .Include(u => u.BuildDetail)
                .ThenInclude(u => u.GraphicCard)
                    .ThenInclude(c => c.FrameSyncType)
            .Include(u => u.BuildDetail)
                .ThenInclude(u => u.GraphicCard)
                    .ThenInclude(c => c.Cooling)
            .Include(u => u.BuildDetail)
                .ThenInclude(u => u.GraphicCard)
                    .ThenInclude(c => c.ExternalPower)
            .Include(u => u.BuildDetail)
                .ThenInclude(u => u.GraphicCard)
                    .ThenInclude(c => c.HardwareImage)

            .Include(u => u.BuildDetail)
                .ThenInclude(u => u.Motherboard)
                    .ThenInclude(c => c.Manufacturer)
            .Include(u => u.BuildDetail)
                .ThenInclude(u => u.Motherboard)
                    .ThenInclude(c => c.FormFactor)
            .Include(u => u.BuildDetail)
                .ThenInclude(u => u.Motherboard)
                    .ThenInclude(c => c.Chipset)
            .Include(u => u.BuildDetail)
                .ThenInclude(u => u.Motherboard)
                    .ThenInclude(c => c.MemoryType)
            .Include(u => u.BuildDetail)
                .ThenInclude(u => u.Motherboard)
                    .ThenInclude(c => c.Color)
            .Include(u => u.BuildDetail)
                .ThenInclude(u => u.Motherboard)
                    .ThenInclude(c => c.Wifi)
            .Include(u => u.BuildDetail)
                .ThenInclude(u => u.Motherboard)
                    .ThenInclude(c => c.Socket)
            .Include(u => u.BuildDetail)
                .ThenInclude(u => u.Motherboard)
                    .ThenInclude(c => c.HardwareImage)
            .Include(u => u.BuildDetail)
                .ThenInclude(u => u.Motherboard)
                    .ThenInclude(c => c.OnBoardEthernet)

            .Include(u => u.BuildDetail)
                .ThenInclude(u => u.PowerSupply)
                    .ThenInclude(c => c.Manufacturer)
            .Include(u => u.BuildDetail)
                .ThenInclude(u => u.PowerSupply)
                    .ThenInclude(c => c.EffieciencyRating)
            .Include(u => u.BuildDetail)
                .ThenInclude(u => u.PowerSupply)
                    .ThenInclude(c => c.ModularType)
            .Include(u => u.BuildDetail)
                .ThenInclude(u => u.PowerSupply)
                    .ThenInclude(c => c.Color)
            .Include(u => u.BuildDetail)
                .ThenInclude(u => u.PowerSupply)
                    .ThenInclude(c => c.PsuType)
            .Include(u => u.BuildDetail)
                .ThenInclude(u => u.PowerSupply)
                    .ThenInclude(c => c.HardwareImage)

            .Include(u => u.BuildDetail)
                .ThenInclude(u => u.Rams)
                    .ThenInclude(u => u.Variant)
            .Include(u => u.BuildDetail)
                .ThenInclude(u => u.Rams)
                    .ThenInclude(u => u.Part)
                        .ThenInclude(c => c.Manufacturer)
            .Include(u => u.BuildDetail)
                .ThenInclude(u => u.Rams)
                    .ThenInclude(u => u.Part)
                        .ThenInclude(c => c.RamType)
            .Include(u => u.BuildDetail)
                .ThenInclude(u => u.Rams)
                    .ThenInclude(u => u.Part)
                        .ThenInclude(c => c.RamVariants)
                            .ThenInclude(r => r.Color)
            .Include(u => u.BuildDetail)
                .ThenInclude(u => u.Rams)
                    .ThenInclude(u => u.Part)
                        .ThenInclude(c => c.HardwareImage)
            .Include(u => u.BuildDetail)
                .ThenInclude(u => u.Rams)
                    .ThenInclude(u => u.Part)
                        .ThenInclude(c => c.FormFactor)

            .Include(u => u.BuildDetail)
                .ThenInclude(u => u.Storages)
                    .ThenInclude(u => u.Variant)
            .Include(u => u.BuildDetail)
                .ThenInclude(u => u.Storages)
                    .ThenInclude(u => u.Part)
                        .ThenInclude(c => c.Manufacturer)
            .Include(u => u.BuildDetail)
                .ThenInclude(u => u.Storages)
                    .ThenInclude(u => u.Part)
                        .ThenInclude(c => c.StorageType)
            .Include(u => u.BuildDetail)
                .ThenInclude(u => u.Storages)
                    .ThenInclude(u => u.Part)
                        .ThenInclude(c => c.FormFactor)
            .Include(u => u.BuildDetail)
                .ThenInclude(u => u.Storages)
                    .ThenInclude(u => u.Part)
                        .ThenInclude(c => c.Interface)
            .Include(u => u.BuildDetail)
                .ThenInclude(u => u.Storages)
                    .ThenInclude(u => u.Part)
                        .ThenInclude(c => c.ListOfStorageVariants)
            .Include(u => u.BuildDetail)
                .ThenInclude(u => u.Storages)
                    .ThenInclude(u => u.Part)
                        .ThenInclude(c => c.HardwareImage)

            .Include(u => u.BuildDetail)
                .ThenInclude(u => u.Owner)

            .Include(u => u.RecommendedBuildCategory);
private IQueryable<RecommendedBuild> _queryWithDetails;

public RecommendedBuild GetBuildById(string id) {
    return QueryWithDetails.Where(b => b.Id == id);
}
```

I have tried to debug the query generated by EF Core. It looks something like this:

```sql
SELECT // long list of columns
FROM EntityAs AS u
LEFT JOIN EntityBs As u1
... // other Included tables
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT A, B, C, Key
    FROM SomeThenIncludedTables AS ux
    INNER JOIN AgainThenIncludedTables AS uy ON ux.Key = uy.Key
) AS t ON uA.Key = t.Key
... // some other similar left joins
```

I would like to know what are the best practices for this kind of complex queries.

[gist to indexes](https://gist.github.com/rthm93/ce9d8544beb34bdcbdd5411e2c426fae)

Comment: Show us your `CREATE INDEX` statements. And don't just put "long list of columns" because returning many non-index-included columns _is part of the problem_.

Comment: Do you *really* need to load every column in 7 tables?

Comment: [Also, every single `IQueryable<T>` in EF Core results in a single `SELECT` query being sent to the DB](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/10878), even if multiple separate queries and result-sets (in a single batch) would be a much more straightforward way to retrieve data - especially when loading object-graphs like you're doing. You should consider using multiple simple separate queries instead of a single complex query (do benchmarks, of course).

Comment: We also need to see your predicate criteria. **Right now you've intentionally removed all the useful information** from your post, which makes your problem impossible to meaningfully diagnose over the Internet, so the only thing we can say, quite flippantly, is  "load less data, lol".

Comment: This sounds like a known performance issue in 3.x with many collection includes. Solved in 5.x, 6.x with [Split Queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/single-split-queries) - basically implementing 1.x, 2.x `Include` behavior.

Comment: Can you provide some benchmarks on how long each part of the logic takes? I'm assuming the longest part of this action is actually querying the data from the DB, since you mentioned looking at the query that is generated. We need more information to help you find the bottlenecks.

Comment: @Dai, I have added the actual query I'm using including the predicate criteria.

Comment: @IvanStoev will upgrade to 6.x and try split queries.

Comment: @Nicholas Ellingson, its a straight forward logic, GET endpoint -> Store -> Query DB. I have tried splitting into multiple small queries and I am seeing some notable improvements.

Comment: It's not clear whether your issues are really caused by a slow response on the server side or by extra processing time on the client. Depending on how many related items you have in the List<EntityI>, it may be worth replacing List<> with HashSet<>. But again, this only helps if the root cause of your performance issues is on the client side. You could use a profiler to figure out whether this is the case.